# Can not catch exception when Marshal.FreeHGlobal error

Tags: c#

I am newbie in C# .NET.
Today, I have a problem, such as below:

I have following code

```
try
{
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(xxx);
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(xxx);
}catch(){// do something}
```

This code has an exception. But some time I can get exception in catch block, some time not.
What wrong in my code which take me can not get exception. Please tell me. Thanks for your help.
P/s: I am sorry about my English.

Comment: What is wrong in your code is that you are trying to free a pointer twice. There is no guarantee that you get an exception when you (potentially) corrupt the memory by doing that. As [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-localfree?redirectedfrom=MSDN#remarks), *If the process tries to examine or modify the memory after it has been freed, heap corruption **may** occur or an access violation exception (EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION) **may** be generated.*

Comment: In short, don't do this.